# Is it possible to make tallow smell like sausage instead of tallow?

Tags: fat, beef-tallow

Mix the liquid tallow with a bunch of spices, that's it?

Works for ground beef that has 40% fat

Comment: I don't think this is an unreasonable question, but from this (and your comments on your other question) I think you're underestimating the difference between a sausage with high fat content, and *pure fat*. A watermelon can be composed of up to 90% water, but it is a very different foodstuff to water.

Comment: Instead of focusing on making tallow, maybe I should create a spicy sausage with 80% fat content?

Comment: Or maybe make a flavored fat?  They have flavored oils and compound butter, so why not a flavored fat

Comment: @Joe, you mean flavored tallow?

Comment: Yes. Tallow is fat, isn’t it?

Comment: yeah well the title kinda asks for that exact same thing, is it not

Answer (score -1):

I have not done this, but I would approach it this way: Determine the style of sausage you are attempting to emulate.  Identify the spices and seasoning content of said sausage.  Add those ingredients to your tallow.  Steep at a low temperature.  Sniff and adjust depending on your use/needs (you may need a higher ratio of these ingredients).  This will take some experimentation, but fats are generally good at retaining flavors and aromas. Strain.

Answer (score -2):

Most of the odourants in sausage stem from amino acids, lipids, and spices and are generated by fermentation, lipid oxidation or Maillard-type reactions.

So, theoretically, this could be done by first identifying the odour-active compounds that are in the type of sausage you want to replicate the smell of, then adding the amino acids and spices, then fermenting/oxidizing (aging) and cooking.

Comment: How do I do that exactly?

Comment: contact a food science lab. see here for some information to guide you: https://www.newfoodmagazine.com/article/89437/tracking-down-aroma-science-meets-senses/

Comment: So your advice is "ask someone who knows the answer"?

Comment: No, the advice is contact someone who can help identify the active compounds. Im sure that something you cannot do in your home kitchen.